# Add comment for audit bunch with Javers

Tags: java, javers

I have Spring Boot app with `javers-spring-boot-starter-sql` and use it in a simple way:

```
@Override
@JaversAuditable
public Company save(Company company) {
    return companyRepository.save(company);
}

@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface CompanyRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Company, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Company> {
}
```

And return reduced action log by `Change.commitMetadata.id` like

```
QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(Account.class);
List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
Set<ChangeBunch> bunches = changes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getId))
        .values().stream()
        .map(item ->
                ChangeBunch.builder().changes(item).comment("My comment").build()
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
return javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(bunches);


private long getId(Change change) {
    return change.getCommitMetadata().orElseThrow().getId().getMajorId();
}
```

And get the output:

```
[
  {
    "comment": "My comment",
    "changes": [
      {
        "changeType": "ValueChange",
        "globalId": {
          "entity": "com.pravvich.demo.model.Account",
          "cdoId": 1
        },
        "commitMetadata": {
          "author": "unauthenticated",
          "properties": [],
          "commitDate": "2021-01-27T02:59:54.361",
          "commitDateInstant": "2021-01-26T23:59:54.361277500Z",
          "id": 7.00
        },
        "property": "number",
        "propertyChangeType": "PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED",
        "left": 6,
        "right": 100
      },
      {
        "changeType": "ValueChange",
        "globalId": {
          "entity": "com.pravvich.demo.model.Account",
          "cdoId": 1
        },
        "commitMetadata": {
          "author": "unauthenticated",
          "properties": [],
          "commitDate": "2021-01-27T02:59:54.361",
          "commitDateInstant": "2021-01-26T23:59:54.361277500Z",
          "id": 7.00
        },
        "property": "balance",
        "propertyChangeType": "PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED",
        "left": 10.8,
        "right": 200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But the comment is hardcoded I need to save the comment somehow in the database prefer just in `javers` table as metadata but how I can extend it? Perhaps I have another way to leave a comment for the change bunch?

Comment: What's the butch ?

Comment: @BartekWalacik butch it's like a group of changes based on commit id. As you can see the list changes group by commit id, and attach comment for each group. From the user side, when I change the company name and company account balance I want to leave the comment why I change these fields, and a comment should be attached to a group of changes.

Comment: I dont get it https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butch :)
btw check the commit properties feature

Comment: @BartekWalacik I'm sorry I mean a bunch its misclick